# How do I make it so my Chrome extension will only inject a script once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I'm using [programmatic injection](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) to inject my extension's code into a page only when the browser action is clicked.

This is what I have on my extension's [event page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) (per the example in [the documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)):

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback(tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content-script.js"});
});
```

However, the way this works, the script is injected **every time** the button is clicked.

How can I change it so that the script is not injected on subsequent button presses - so that it is inserted *only the first time* the button is clicked on that page?

Comment: Do you want to run the code only once per page, once per window or once in the lifetime of the browsing session?

Comment: Actually, *does* this cause the script to be injected multiple times? I seem to recall Philip Bump at the Washington Post having that *exact problem*, that running `executeScript` multiple times only caused the script to run the first time, and asking me about it (which is why I'm credited [in this article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/12/16/now-you-can-fact-check-trumps-tweets-in-the-tweets-themselves/)).

Comment: Yes, `chrome.tabs.executeScript` tries to run a script whenever you call it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a global variable in your contentscript to judge if the contentscript has been executed.

```
if (something) { return; }
```

Comment: Global variables in content scripts are only global to the running script.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley content scripts from the same extension on the same page share the same execution environment, so a global variable declared in a first run of your script would be seen by a second run.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley just as rsanchez says.

Comment: Can't make this work. return will not work outside a function, and inside it will only exit the function (I should try `exit()`, but... read on). How is `something` defined? `var something = true`?

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of right now (easy and simple) is to use [html5webstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). Since you are running this code from your background or popup page it will be ok.

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("isAlreadyInjected")){
   localStorage['isAlreadyInjected'] = "true";
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback(tab){chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content-script.js"});});}
```

So, the very first time when storage value "isAlreadyInjected" does not exist, the listener will be added. Afterwards, even when the browser closes and opens again this value will remain stored and so the listener will not be added to your extension.

**UPDATE**

As your background page loads only once at the beginning, it can keep variable that is not re-initialized with the browser action click. So you can use that variable to do your job!

background.js

```
var isAlreadyInjected =false;
function isInjected(){

if(!isAlreadyInjected ){
    isAlreadyInjected=true;
    return false;
 }
 else
    return true;
}
```

popup.js

```
var bgpage=chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
 if(!bgpage.isInjected()){
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback(tab) {chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content-script.js"});});
}
```

or

```
var bgpage=chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback(tab) { 
 if(!bgpage.isInjected()){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content-script.js"});
}});
```

Comment: It's not about re-adding the listener (which, by the way, *is* something you want to happen). It's about not taking the action *in* the listener more than once.

Comment: This wouldn't have worked for two reasons - it uses null for the tabid so it would only inject once and then skip when clicked against other tabs and the `isAlreadyInjected` value would remain true for the whole session so it doesnt allow page reloads, etc until the browser is closed.

Comment: AFTER UPDATE: background.js variables won't be cleared after reloading a page. So if you reload a page, your code won't be there, but it won't be injected either.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question but I encountered the issue now that Manifest V3 is out and persistent background pages have been replaced with service workers. I figured I'd give what I used as a solution in case anyone else needs it. Code must be executed within the global context of the content script. Anytime it tries to inject it again, the relevant code will only be executed if the global variable is not defined.

```
if (typeof hasBeenExecuted === 'undefined') {
    // Code that needs to execute only once goes here
}
var hasBeenExecuted = true;
```

Hopefully this is helpful for someone else who comes across the question.